# I have an issue with collaborating in Unity via Github

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github, collaboration

I am a new coder attempting to work with another person in Unity. I have GitHub Desktop installed. I opened the repository to it and cloned it to my local machine. That was weird but eventually, I messed around and was able to open it in Unity. When opening it in Unity, only my scripts remain. The entire scene is empty. I can tell the folder I opened had the scene in it but it does not show up when opening it in Unity. How do I fix and prevent this so I can collaborate? I am using UnityHub 3.0.0, the latest version of GitHub desktop, and unity 2020.3.24f1. I am coding in C#. There were no errors, the scene was just missing.

Comment: Could be the person you are collaborating with hasnt upload it correctly. It’s impossible to tell. Any errors?

Comment: Sounds like a Git LFS (large file storage) issue. You most probably didn't checkout the LFS files correctly => they are basically just pointers and itself useless until you checkout the actual LFS content. Try running `git fetch origin master` or whatever your origin and branch are called. This will download the actual content instead of any pointer files

Comment: I am the person who uploaded it however I am very new to doing this. It works on my and my collaborator's home computers but not on a much poorer computer I don't have administrator access to. Could it be a perms issue? It could be an issue with not being able to handle the file size on that computer perhaps, I am not sure.